# SWITCH does not work in SSRS (Throws Error)

Tags: reporting-services, switch-statement, ssrs-2008-r2, iif

Excuse me, English is not my native language.
The formula does not work
(with
(Sum (iif (Fields! Ap_group.Value Like "D", Fields! Sales90__90.Value, Nothing)) = 0 And Sum (iif (Fields! Ap_group.Value Like "D", Fields! Sales30__30.Value, Nothing)) = 0) produces Error!

The formula itself:

```
= Switch ((Sum (iif (Fields! Ap_group.Value Like "D", Fields! Sales90__90.Value, Nothing)) = 0 And Sum (iif (Fields! Ap_group.Value Like "D", Fields! Sales30__30.Value, Nothing)) = 0), Nothing,

 Sum (iif (Fields! Ap_group.Value Like "D", Fields! Sales90__90.Value, Nothing)) - Sum (iif (Fields! Ap_group.Value Like "D", Fields! Sales30__30.Value, Nothing)) = 0,
 Sum (iif (Fields! Ap_group.Value Like "D", Fields! StockQty_up.Value, Nothing)) / Sum (iif (Fields! Ap_group.Value Like "D", Fields! Sales90__90.Value, Nothing)),

  Sum (iif (Fields! Ap_group.Value Like "D", Fields! Sales90__90.Value, Nothing)) - Sum (iif (Fields! Ap_group.Value Like "D", Fields! Sales30__30.Value, Nothing))> 0,
   Sum (iif (Fields! Ap_group.Value Like "D", Fields! StockQty_up.Value, Nothing)) / Sum (iif (Fields! Ap_group.Value Like "D", Fields! Sales90__90.Value, Nothing)),

   Sum (iif (Fields! Ap_group.Value Like "D", Fields! Sales90__90.Value, Nothing)) - Sum (iif (Fields! Ap_group.Value Like "D", Fields! Sales30__30.Value, Nothing)) <0,
    Sum (iif (Fields! Ap_group.Value Like "D", Fields! StockQty_up.Value, Nothing)) / Sum (iif (Fields! Ap_group.Value Like "D", Fields! Sales30__30.Value, Nothing))
)
```

Can you please tell me what is the mistake?

Comment: if you briefly need to implement the formula:
a / max (b, c)
Where b, c - different fields of the table
There may be cases:
1) c = b = 0 --> nothing -Nothing is displayed in the report
2) c = b --> a / b
3) b> c --> a / b
4) b <c --> a / c

Comment: Although the structure looks OK (I think) there are spaces after each instance of `Fields!`

Comment: in reality there are no gaps, it is inserted here like this

Comment: you could try a few things to break it down. First replace `Nothing` with 0. Seconds, add columns to your report with each of the expressions evaluated so you can see exactly what is being compared. Once you have done that, if you still cannot fix the problem, post the results of these tests and include some sample data with the expected outcome or it will be very difficult to help you

Comment: Thanks I did it. I added a small number to the denominator of the formula and this error went away